# Pelican blog - Verify ownership Bing webmaster

Tags: blogs, bing, pelican, bing-webmaster-tools

To verify ownership of my blog, the bing webmaster requires one of the following three approaches:

1. Upload the file "BingSiteAuth.xml" to my website as https://mywebsite/BingSiteAuth.xml
2. Copy and paste a meta tag in my default webpage e.g. `<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="...." />`
   An example given:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="...." />
        <title>Your SEO optimized title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        page contents
    </body>
</html>
```

3. Add CNAME record to DNS

### Question:

What would be the easiest approach and what would be the steps for a beginner ?

Note I am using the AboutWilson template in Pelican. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the copy and paste meta tag would be the easiest, i have done it on my blog. All you need to do is go to your theme template directory and paste the required meta tag line in the *base.html* file in the head section.